# Some troubles with きかせていただきたい

Tags: meaning, kanji, keigo

I am intending to say:

> もう一度質問を聞いてください。

To make much it more indirect I wanted to rephrase it as:

> もう一度質問をきかせていただきたいです。

However, since きく can mean (among others) both *listen to* and *ask*, this sentence can be understood as

> 1. I would like to ask my question once more.

or

> 2. I would like to hear your question once more.

Would the ambiguity vanish if I use 訊く to force the first interpretation? Is there any other way to clear this ambiguity?

Comment: I think a more usual way is to say: ________　もう一度質問を繰り返してもよろしいですか？_______________　もう一度別の言葉で質問させていただけますか？　　・・・・いただいて、よろしいでしょうか？　________　　いまの私の言い方では分かりにくかったかもしれないので、・・・・　_______________　((( Comment box and ENTER (for kanji henkan) are not working together for me. )))

Comment: @H.Ha If you're having problems with using enter to convert kana to kanji in comments, could you let SE know by posting here on meta? http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1602/1478  Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, for "ask a question" you'd use 「質問(を)する」「聞く(訊く)」「尋ねる」 etc., and 質問を聞く sounds more like "listen to a question".

So your 1st example 「もう一度質問を聞いてください。」 would normally be understood as "Please listen to my question once more", "I would like to repeat my question."

To say "I'd like you to hear my question once more" or "I would like to repeat my question" politely and indirectly, I think you could say:

> もう一度質問を聞いていただきたいのですが。
>   もう一度質問をお聞きいただけないでしょうか。
>   もう一度質問をお聞きいただけますか。
>   質問を繰り返させていただいてもよろしいでしょうか。
>   etc...

To say "I would like to ask my question one more time" politely and indirectly:

> もう一度質問させていただきたいのですが。/ いただいてもよろしいでしょうか。
>   もう一度お聞きしてもよろしいでしょうか。
>   もう一度お尋ねしてもよろしいでしょうか。
>   もう一度お伺いしてもよろしいでしょうか。*
>   etc...

(*もう一度お伺いしてもよろしいでしょうか can also mean "Could you repeat that, please?")

---

「もう一度質問を聞いてください。」 *might* be interpreted as "Please ask your question once more", but this would normally be said as:

> もう一度質問(を)**して**ください。 
>   もう一度質問を言ってください / おっしゃってください。
>   もう一度質問を聞かせてください。
>   質問をもう一度お願いします。
>   etc.

To say "Please ask your question once more" or "I would like to hear your question once more" politely and indirectly, you could say:

> もう一度質問していただけますか / (ご)質問をおっしゃっていただけますか。
>   もう一度(ご)質問を聞かせていただけますか / お聞かせ願えますか。
>   (ご)質問をもう一度お伺いできますか / お願いできますか。
>   etc...

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. In fact I wanted to say "I would like to hear your question once more" (the first interpretation you suggest) so I should have said that I intended to say "もう一度質問をしてください". But since you gave a lot of details everything is clear now. Thank you

Comment: Oops so it seems like I misread your question.. Let me update my post when I have time

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking the asker to repeat his / her question, neither “もう一度質問を聞いてください” or “もう一度質問をきかせていただきたいです” sounds smooth in Japanese to me, nor is grammatical.

I would say ”(済みませんが）只今の質問、もう一度繰り返して頂けませんか？" or "もう一度言って(仰って)頂けますか？- Excuse me, would you repeat your question ( say it) again?”

Comment: I am just curious but what make you say that those two sentences are not grammatical. Sure, they may not sound smooth but that's a completely different problem.

Comment: @永劫回帰 If you want to understand what the asker is asking, i.e. the gist of the asker's question, you would say "please repeat your question, not  " もう一度質問を聞いてください", which means "Please listen my question once more." It doesn't make sense."もう一度質問をきかせていただきたいです" is very awkward Japanese.  If it's gramatically right, it does not sound awkward to anyone.